# RAM usage stacking up with each iteration

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, ram

I am opening a list of asm files, and closing them after extracting arrays from them. I had issues with RAM usage which is solved now.

When I was appending the extracted arrays (in array format) in a list, the RAM usage kept stacking up with each iteration. However, when I changed my code to change the format of the extracted arrays to list before appending, the issue resolved. Please see line i_arrays.append(h.tolist()). I'm just trying to understand why was the RAM usage stacking up when I was storing np arrays.

Code >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```py
t1_start = process_time() 

files = os.listdir('asmFiles')
i_arrays=[]
file_names=[]
for i in tqdm(files[0:1501]):
    f_name=i.split('.')[0] 
    file_names.append(f_name)
    b='asmFiles/'+str(i)
    f=open(b,'rb')
    ln=os.path.getsize(b)
    width=int(ln**0.5)
    rem=ln%width
    a = array.array("B")
    a.fromfile(f,ln-rem)
    f.close()
    g=np.reshape(a,(int(len(a)/width),width))
    g=np.uint(g)
    h=g[0][0:800]
    i_arrays.append(h.tolist())
print(psutil.virtual_memory()[2])

t1_stop = process_time()
print("Elapsed time during the whole program in seconds:",t1_stop-t1_start)
```